# Some users needed to press F5 to get updated images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iis

I work on an ASP.NET MVC solution under IIS. In this solution I have some images. Yesterday I modified these images and published the solution under IIS. When I visited the pages containing these images I saw my modifications.

**BUT** some users didn't. They had to press F5 to have the modified images to show. They use Internet Explorer 11.

Any idea why ?

Comment: [This article](http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet) on 'cache busting' might be handy for you.

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks for the link.

Comment: Great, hope it helps you.